# import path auto-completion not working with npm package with multiple entrypoints (exports)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I have built and published a React UI component library.
It was components like `Button`, `Checkbox`, etc. - for which I have created separate directories (each having its own `index.ts`).
Here is the directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── components.json
├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── button
│   │   │   ├── button.tsx
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── checkbox
│   │   │   ├── checkbox.tsx
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── globals.css
│   └── lib
│       └── utils.ts
├── tailwind.config.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsup.config.ts
```

I have the following exports in my `package.json` file:

```js
  "exports": {
    "./components/button": {
      "import": "./dist/components/button/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/components/button/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/button/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./components/calendar": {
      "import": "./dist/components/calendar/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/components/calendar/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/calendar/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./components/card": {
      "import": "./dist/components/card/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/components/card/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/card/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./components/carousel": {
      "import": "./dist/components/carousel/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/components/carousel/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/carousel/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./components/checkbox": {
      "import": "./dist/components/checkbox/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/components/checkbox/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/components/checkbox/index.d.ts"
    },
```

I am able to import these in other projects with

`import * from "@mypackage/ui/components/button";`

However, the path `/components/button` doesn't auto-complete in any of the IDEs (tried VS Code and WebStorm)

Am I missing some types or configuration somewhere?

Comment: That looks to me like everything's configured to work. How are you trying to autocomplete the imports? By referencing something from the module? Can you tell us what package it is?

Comment: Trying to type the path in the import statement itself. It auto completes till @trycreo/ui (which is the package name). After that it doesn't suggest the sub paths. But if I type the full sub path (i.e., @trycreo/ui/components/button), it works (red squiggly disappears and the import works).

Comment: Check the code for this version of the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@trycreo/ui/v/6.0.18?activeTab=code

Comment: Let me know if you'd like to see other parts of the code that is not published.

Comment: Have just tried to install versions 6.0.18 and 6.0.48. The former has "main", "module", and "types" in the package.json that point to files that don't exist. The latter publishes a "dist/src/etc/etc" which, again, none of the references correctly point at. Fix your build so that it outputs your files directly into "dist", make sure the build directory contains what you'd expect, update the "main", "module", and "types" to point at existing files in the "dist" directory, and then you can worry about pointing the "exports" at additional files within there.

Comment: @JakeSidSmith Thanks for putting in the time to try them out. In 6.0.18, we do not have a need to have a main entrypoint, so I just added the commonly used values even though there are no such files present at those locations. I am not sure if a main entrypoint is needed in our case, and if it's a requirement for packaging. Because if I have two components they can be imported using two different paths (exports), like `from "@trycreo/ui/button"` and `from "trycreo/ui/checkbox"`. I could have added a main index file (barrel file) but sometimes the exports may have the same name.